# Passing a r-value-reference to constructor to reduce copies

Tags: c++, reference

I have the following code lines

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utility>

class A
{
    public: // member functions
        explicit A(int && Val)
        {
            _val = std::move(Val); // \2\
        }
        virtual ~A(){}

    private: // member variables
        int _val = 0;

    private: // member functions
        A(const A &) = delete;
        A& operator = (const A &) = delete;
        A(A &&) = delete;
        A&& operator = (A &&) = delete;
};


int main()
{
    A a01{3}; // \1\
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to ask how many copies did I make from `\1\` to `\2\`?

Comment: Note that you're not making copies, but assigning values.

Comment: It's an interesting homework assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile, but after making the changes needed for it to compile, it does nothing and compiles into this x86 assembly because none of it's values are ever used:

```
main:
  xor eax, eax
  ret
```

https://godbolt.org/z/q70EMb

Modifying the code so that it requires the output of the `_val` member variable (with a print statement) shows that with optimizations it simply moves the value `0x03` into a register and prints it:

```
.LC0:
  .string "%d\n"
main:
  sub rsp, 8
  mov esi, 3
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
  xor eax, eax
  call printf
  xor eax, eax
  add rsp, 8
  ret
```

https://godbolt.org/z/JG73Ll

If you disable optimizations in an attempt to get the compiler to output a more verbose version of the program:

```
A::A(int&&):
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  sub rsp, 16
  mov QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
  mov QWORD PTR [rbp-16], rsi
  mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
  mov DWORD PTR [rax], 0
  mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  mov rdi, rax
  call std::remove_reference<int&>::type&& std::move<int&>(int&)
  mov edx, DWORD PTR [rax]
  mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
  mov DWORD PTR [rax], edx
  nop
  leave
  ret
.LC0:
  .string "%d\n"
main:
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  sub rsp, 16
  mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 3
  lea rdx, [rbp-4]
  lea rax, [rbp-8]
  mov rsi, rdx
  mov rdi, rax
  call A::A(int&&)
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
  mov esi, eax
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
  mov eax, 0
  call printf
  mov eax, 0
  leave
  ret
std::remove_reference<int&>::type&& std::move<int&>(int&):
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  mov QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
  mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
  pop rbp
  ret
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ZTK40d

The answer to your question depends on how your program is compiled and how copy elision is enforced, as well as if there is any benefit in the case of an `int` to not "copying" a value, since an `int*` and `int` likely take up the same amount of memory.

Answer (score 0):

your are merely assigning a value, not copying. Nevertheless, you can have a static member in your class that is incremented everytime this method is called!

```
class A
{

    public: // member functions
        static int counter = 0;
        explicit A(int && Val)
        {
            _val = std::move(Val); // \2\
            counter++;
        }
        ....
```